# Auto-generate columns in telerik mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am working on mvc application with telerik controls for mvc tools and Entity Framework for db connectivity.
 In my application i have telerik MVC grid. the columns for the grid have to be generated automatically based on the rows of a table . I am in  need of using a list of domain class (property) as model for the grid. And the columns for the grid should be generated automatically based on the model. So how can i create the domain class dynamically based on the rows of a table. ie each row in the table has to be represented as  equivalent property in  the domain class. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated .

Thanks in advance
Boney C David

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `column.AutoGenerate` that Telerik support?

I don't know what is your project requirement but I don't think that creating such a "very dynamic" domain or class is a good idea.

If you don't wanna use AutoGenerated columns, please give us more details about your problem.